# Getting stored memory number instead

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file-io

I am suppose to make a two files one named input and the other named output

in the input file i have: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dignissim,  tincidunt vitae nisi eu viverra. Sed, consequat.

which should be 128 elements for a string array.

what i am trying to do is make the program read from the input file word by word into a string array of 128 elements.

here is the code i came up with so far:

```
int main(){
string Lnm[128];
int l = 0;
//input file and output file.
fstream theInput("Input.txt", ios::in);
fstream theOutput("Output.txt", ios::out);

//checks if file is there
if (!theInput.good()){
    cout << "A PROBLEM HAS OCCURED!\n" << "______________________________\n" << "ERROR: File does not exist! Please make a valid file.\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

for (Lnm; getline(theInput, Lnm[l], '\n');) {
    cout << Lnm << endl;
}

//checking      

if (theInput.eof()){
    cout << "Successful!\n";
    theOutput << Lnm[l] << "\n";

}
else if (theInput.fail()){
    cout << "Invalid Input\n";
}
else if (theInput.bad()){
    cout << "Error! go and fix the problem.\n";
}
theInput.close();
theOutput.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

my problem is that I am getting where the thing is stored, or at least that's what I think it is. How would I make it so it shows the text and imports it to the output?

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
for (Lnm; getline(theInput, Lnm[l], '\n');) {
    cout << Lnm << endl;
}
```

don't increment `l`. You end up reading the words into only `Lnm[0]` since `l` is initialized to `0`.

Also, `cout << Lnm << endl;` will probably just print a pointer -- the pointer to the first element of `Lnm`.

Change them to:

```
for ( l = 0; getline(theInput, Lnm[l], '\n'); ++l ) {
    cout << Lnm[l] << endl;
}
```

When you are ready to print the strings to the output file, you need to use:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
   theOutput << Lnm[i] << "\n";
}
```

**PS** I would use `numLines` instead of `l`. That will make the code a bit more readable.